# Как можно установить onClickListener на View_1 который находится внизу другого View (View_2)

Tags: android, android-layout

Приветствую ! Как можно установить onClickListener на View_1 который находится внизу другого View (View_2). View_2 должен отображаться поверх View_1, но другой роли у него нет, но кликабельным должен быть именно View_1.

Comment: установить View2 свойство `android:clickable = "false"` ?

Comment: Увы, но нет, так пробовал

Comment: тогда нужно больше подробностей, код, разметка, какая проблема и как проявляется